# Possible to put today's date as an alias?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to call an access function in the alias.  But it is not possible, it takes it as a literal.  Is there a way to put today's date in an alias?  AS Date() obviously doesn't work.

thanks

For those wondering the exported spreadsheet needs to have todays date+"Delivery" as the column name, i.e. 6/12DeliveryDate.

Comment: What is your full query? I'm not following what you're expecting from what you've described

Comment: Its a requirement that was given.  I am automating a process that included a query, and one of the requirements was that the final report format should have todays date"Delivery Date" i.e. 6/12DeliveryDate as a column name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just thinking about this backwards. Why not just alias the output of the date? I cannot see a benefit...which is probably why it is not allowed

```
Date() AS Today
```

Comment: This sounds plausible but I think he really wants the date as the alias name.

Answer (score 1):

The "AS" keyword exists to give a specific column a name.  For example:

`SELECT Date() As Today`

Means to return the current date in a column labelled `Today`.

`SELECT '2013-06-12' as Date()`

doesn't make any sense... unless you are trying to name the column with today's date, which likewise sounds off.  The only way I could think to accomplish this would be with some type of dynamic sql that passes today's date as the column name.  Such that the query would read:

`SELECT 'asdf' as [2013-06-12]`

I'm not entirely sure how to construct that in MS Access.  In sql server it would be something like:

```
declare @dateName varchar(20) 
declare @sql varchar(1000)
set @dateName = convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 105)

set @sql = 'SELECT Col1 as [' + @dateName + ']'

exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a column alias (a.k.a. replacement column name) using a function. Aliases must be "hard-coded" in the query.

Why do you want a column to have the current date, anyway? Any consumer of your query's data will have a hard time dealing with the column name changing all the time. You won't be able to bind it to anything. Reports and forms won't work. Instead, make the column name something like `TodayValue`, then in your presentation layer, simply display today's date as the label (in a Form or Report you'd have to use a textbox but can style it to look like a label).

Answer (score 0):

If the final report should have it then do this on the report. Leave the query data alone (since this has nothing to do with the data and everything to do with the report generation) and in your report's header do the concatenation of `now()` and `Delivery Date`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add a column alias using a [dynamic query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390420/create-a-query-dynamically-through-code-in-msaccess-2003-vba) in which you call the `date()` function and append your text.