# Export Access data into Excel workbook and split data into multiple sheets based on column value

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

**Sample data (local Access table called 'Pets_data_table')**

```
ID | Pet_Type | Pet_Owner

1      Dog        Jane Doe         
2      Cat        John Doe
3      Hamster    Bob Doe
4      Dog        Melissa Doe 
5      Cat        Aaron Doe
```

At the moment, I can export the data in this table to one Excel workbook, and split the data into multiple sheets within that Excel workbook according to distinct values of a specific field. I use the following VBA to split the data according to distinct values of the 'Pet_Type' field:

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "C:\Desktop\" & "Pets_dataset_export_" & format(date(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx" 
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Qry - Dog", strPath, True, "Dog"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Qry - Cat", strPath, True, "Cat"
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, 10, "Qry - Hamster", strPath, True, "Hamster"

    Set db = Nothing
    MsgBox "Export operation completed"
```

This performs well when the field I am splitting the data with has a small number of distinct values.

However, it is inefficient when there are a large number of distinct values in the field I want to split the data with.

I would like to implement a more dynamic approach that allows me to split a dataset with a field that has 1...n number of distinct values.

Comment: One way would be to load everything then sort on the Pet_Type field then loop through till it changes and create a new sheet each time with the new Pet_type value becoming the name of the sheet.

Comment: It would be much easier to use transferspreadsheet and suitable queries.

Comment: @Fionnuala: Updated the VBA to reflect the easier way of using my current approach.

Comment: With Fionnuala's approach you still need to create a new query for each distinct animal type.  To do this use sql to get a distinct list of animals then step through them creating each query dynamically.  Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390420/create-a-query-dynamically-through-code-in-msaccess-2003-vba) for instruction on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load a single recordset based on a query which gives you the unique pet types ...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT p.Pet_Type
FROM Pets_data_table AS p;
```

Then walk that recordset, alter a saved query (*qryExportMe*) to `SELECT` the current `Pet_Type`, and export the query ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strPath As String
Dim strSelectOneType As String
Dim strSelectPetTypes As String

' (change strPath back to what you need)
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "Pets_dataset_export_" & _
    Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xlsx"
strSelectPetTypes = "SELECT DISTINCT p.Pet_Type" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM Pets_data_table AS p;"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSelectPetTypes, dbOpenSnapshot)
Do While Not rs.EOF
    strSelectOneType = "SELECT p.ID, p.Pet_Type, p.Pet_Owner" & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM Pets_data_table AS p" & vbCrLf & _
        "WHERE p.Pet_Type='" & rs!Pet_Type.Value & "';"
    Debug.Print strSelectOneType
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryExportMe")
    qdf.SQL = strSelectOneType
    qdf.Close
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "qryExportMe", strPath, True, rs!Pet_Type.Value
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```

Note that code requires that the saved query, *qryExportMe*, exists.  But its SQL property doesn't matter because you'll change it each time through the main `Do While` loop.