# How to reference a combo box in a SQL statement and run the statement in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am attempting to let users use a form to insert data into the table Inventory2Locaton in Microsoft access. They will select data from two combo boxes and then press an add button to add the data to the table.

The query I use is

```
INSERT INTO Inventory2Location
VALUES (ComboPart.value, ComboOver.value);
```

but it won't actually pull `ComboPart.value` or `ComboOver.value` from the combo boxes.

I also cannot figure out how to run this query by clicking the button. I have the module with

```
Private Sub CommandAdd_Click()
```

but don't know what VBA code will run the query.

I am quite familiar with VBA from excel experience and have taken a class on SQL but I am very new to access and don't understand how to put the two together.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390420/create-a-query-dynamically-through-code-in-msaccess-2003-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
sqlStr = "INSERT INTO Inventory2Location VALUES (" & ComboPart.Value & " ," & ComboOver.value & ");"
```

You need to get the value of the combo box, what you are doing is just making `ComboPart.Value` a literal string value.

As for this code,

```
Private Sub CommandAdd_Click()
```

It is auto generated code so it should be attached to something to fire it when you click on it.

Comment: This returns a couple errors. With one ComboPart value it returns a "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '"U"CHANFRAME'" ("U"CHANFRAME is the part number in the ComboPart value.

The other isn't exactly an error but it will simply give me a message box pop up to manually enter the text. The message box will be named what I want to be entered into it.

Comment: found the syntax error in the string. It was simply missing a couple apostrophes. This code works 

    "INSERT INTO Inventory2Location VALUES ('" & ComboPart.Value & "' ,'" & ComboOver.Value & "');"

Answer (score 1):

I would offer that a better solution would be to set the Form's "Record Source" property to Inventory2Location.  Then, on the Data tab of the Form Properties, set "Data Entry" to "Yes".   This will make it so the form can only add records to the table.

Next, for each control that represents a value in the table you want the user to add, go into that control's properties and set the `Control Source` to the field you want updated.

Then, on the Event tab of the "Save" button, remove `[Event Procedure]` and click the `...` button.  Select `Macro Builder`.  This will create an embedded Macro in the form.  The macro is simply two commands.  One to save the current record and the other to close the form.

```
RunMenuCommand
       Command  SaveRecord
CloseWindow
   Object Type  Form
   Object Name  =[Screen].[ActiveForm].Name
          Save  Prompt
```

Be sure to put the equals sign in front of `[Screen]`.

The benefits of this approach are:

- If an error occurs due to duplicate keys or bad input, Access will take care of notifying the user of the problem.   Using VBA you would need to trap for those type of errors.
- By using the Embedded macro, you should be able to outright eliminate a code module attached to the form (Turn `Has Module` to `No` in the *Other* tab for the form's properties).  This turns it into a *lightweight form* which means it runs quicker and does not suffer from the usual code corruption that creeps into Access.
- Lastly, you should be able to run the form without elevated trust settings granted to the database.  So then you don't need to worry about people clicking the "Enable" button in order for the form to work properly.

Comment: How will this method know which data fields to to put into the table?

Comment: You bind the control (e.g. Combo Box) to the table field.  In the control's properties you will use "Control Source"